# change background* without refresh

Tags: jquery, css

I have a website with images.

On each image is one mouse over a favourit icon visible.

if the user clicks it it wil be added to theyr favourits with:

```
 $.post("favoriet.php", { aid: aid } );
```

By default the add to favourit icon has the following css

```
.imgContainer div:hover a,
.imgContainer div:focus a 
{
background: url(/media/img/favourit25.PNG);
}
```

but if a user has clicked favourit the image must change to delete.PNG

without refreshing the page.

Is there any way i can do this?

Example of how it looks: http://jsfiddle.net/9auEQ/4/

i want to change the top left picture if clicked

if i use

```
function toevoegenFavo(aid) 
{       
    alert("the picture is added.");
    $.post("favoriet.php", { aid: aid } );
    $('.imgContainer').toggleClass('fav');
}
```

the toggleClass works and all images change (instead of only the 1 i clicked)

```
<script>
$('.imgContainer').click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass('fav');
});
 </script>
```

dosnt do a thing for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle a class on your `.imgContainer` and then add a style to override the "add to favs" background.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AwBF7/1/)

**JS**

```
$('.imgContainer').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('fav');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.imgContainer.fav div:hover a,
.imgContainer.fav div:focus a {
    background: url(http://www.letsgomobile.org/images/reviews/0102/samsung-camera-phone-test-pictures.jpg);

}
```

Comment: i put  <script>
 $('.imgContainer').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('fav');
});
 </script> in my code but it aint working? the jsfiddle looks perfect

Comment: Did you include the .fav styles also?

Comment: yes in my css i have .imgContainer.fav div:hover a,
.imgContainer.fav div:focus a {
    background: url(http://www.letsgomobile.org/images/reviews/0102/samsung-camera-phone-test-pictures.jpg);
    
}
.imgContainer div {
    float:left;
}
.imgContainer img {  
 height:175px;
 min-height:175px;
 max-width:96%;
 max-height:96%;
}
.imgContainer a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    }
.imgContainer div:hover a,
.imgContainer div:focus a {
    background: url(/media/img/favourit25.PNG);
    }
but the class fav dosnt  get added

Comment: if i add in my php file <div class="imgContainer fav" onclick="javascript:void(viewer.show(<?php echo $i ?>))">  so after imgContainer    fav manualy it look like it should but fav wont be added.

Comment: Or do i need to add it some where else then in the header.